# Mirroring the ROS debians not working with reprepro

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Upon trying to mirror some packages with a filter list at http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu

I'm running into this error with reprepro:

```
conf/updates:
Name: pr2-ros-pkgs
Suite: trusty
Method: http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/
ComponentS: main
Architectures: amd64
FilterList: purge pr2rosdeps.packages
DownloadListsAs: .gz
VerifyRelease: blindtrust


Could not find 'main/debian-installer/binary-amd64/Packages' within './lists/pr2-ros-pkgs_trusty_InRelease'
```

IS this done by design to prevent this sort of updating/access from this repo, or just a bug?

Edit: adding more info

It seems that the archive.ubuntu.com also provides a `trusty/main/debian-installer` in its `conf/dists` file. I'm thinking that this is preventing the merge of the ROS pkgs into my repo because the ros repo doesn/t have a `trusty/main/debian-installer`, which its expecting it to.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217858/mirroring-the-ros-debians-not-working-with-reprepro/) by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 644 on 2015-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to solve this by separating the grabbing of the ROS packages into a seperate distribution clause in my conf/distributions file.

---

Originally posted by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) with karma: 644 on 2015-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1